# algún otra forma mas sencilla para validar los números de letras en C++?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int num;
cout<<"Ingrese un numero"<<endl;
    while((cin>>num).fail())    {
        cin>>num;
        fflush(stdin);
        cin.clear();
        system ("cls");
        cout<<"\tError"<<endl;
        cout<<"Ingrese nuevamente...  "<<endl;
        cout<<"Ingrese nuevamente "<<endl;
    }
    getch ();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Cuidado con fflush

Como ya he comentado en otras ocasiones. `fflush` está diseñado para ser usado con dispositivos de **salida**. En el caso de dispositivos de entrada, el resultado es indeterminado (que funcione o no depende de la librería que uses en cada momento).

Así que eso de

```
fflush(stdin);
```

... mejor eliminalo.

### Alternativas a fflush

Dado que estás usando `cin` (algo lógico dado que estás programando en C++... puedes usar esto:

```
#include <limits>

std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<int>::max(),'\n');
```

El método `ignore` permite descartar un número dado de caracteres o hasta que se encuentre el caracter pasado como argumento (lo que llegue antes). En el ejemplo que te pongo se descartarán todos los caracteres hasta encontrar un salto de línea.

`numeric_limits` es una plantilla que ofrece información sobre los tipos nativos de C++. En este caso el método `max` devuelve el valor máximo que se puede almacenar por una variable de tipo `int`.

### Apuntes finales

Lo mejor es aislar el código en una única función, de tal forma que puedas reutilizarla cuantas veces quieras. La implementación de esta función es libre... si usas C++17 o superior yo tiraría de `std::optional`:

```
std::optional<int> LeerEntero()
{
  int valor;
  std::cin >> valor;

  if( std::cin.fail() )
  {
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<int>::max(),'\n');
    return std::nullopt;
  }

  return valor;
}

int main()
{
  std::optional<int> valor;
  while( true )
  {
    valor = LeerEntero();
    if( valor.has_value() )
      break;
  }

  std::cout << *valor;
}
```

En versiones anteriores podrías o bien devolver un `pair`:

```
std::pair<int,bool> LeerEntero()
{
  int valor;
  bool ok = true;
  std::cin >> valor;

  if( std::cin.fail()  )
  {
    ok = false;
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<int>::max(),'\n');
  }

  return std::make_pair(valor,ok);
}

int main()
{
  int valor;
  while( true )
  {
    bool ok;
    std::tie(valor,ok) = LeerEntero();
    if( ok )
      break;
  }

  std::cout << valor;
}
```

... o usar una referencia (quizás para este caso concreto la versión más legible):

```
bool LeerEntero(int& numero)
{
  bool ok = true;
  std::cin >> numero;

  if( std::cin.fail()  )
  {
    ok = false;
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<int>::max(),'\n');
  }

  return ok;
}

int main()
{
  int valor;
  while( true )
  {
    if( LeerEntero(valor) )
      break;
  }

  std::cout << valor;
}
```